# How to place blocks at equal distance from each other?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, grid

I'm using bootstrap blocks called jumbotron and I can't get my blocks to fit in the row because these blocks have their own padding. I need three ones on one row. When I try to align them with **col-xs-3** they don't look proportional. How to do so? Thanks in advance.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alexnotonfire/thcmvf9o/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="events">
    <div class="row">

        <li class="col-xs-4 jumbotron">
          some text
        </li>

        <li class="col-xs-4 jumbotron">
          some text
        </li>

        <li class="col-xs-4 jumbotron">
          some text
        </li>

        <li class="col-xs-4 jumbotron">
          some text
        </li>

        <li class="col-xs-4 jumbotron">
          some text
        </li>

        <li class="col-xs-4 jumbotron">
          some text
        </li>

    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    margin: 30px 60px;
    border: solid;
}

.row {
    margin: 8px 0;
}

.events {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you should be combining the jumbotron class with a col

Comment: @Jay Ok, eventually I need something like [this](http://imgur.com/YkOqg8U).

Comment: That's fine. I have a question for you though. Why are you using the jumbotron class? Is it imperative that you do so? If not then I think just using the columns on there own should be fine to achieve that. Just make sure that they add up to 12 in each row.

Comment: Try reducing padding and margin from container, row and jumbotron

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @Jay I got it working using div blocks and bootstrap grid.

Answer (score 1):

Add li as below and set margin:0 for jumbotron

```
<li class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="jumbotron">some text</div>
</li>

.jumbotron {
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: Is this not just a _hacky_ way round badly formed html?

Comment: Instead of li you can use div's. But you should not add include .jumbotron class with .col-* class